# How to delete gaps but not change polygon boundaries with v.clean in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, topology, v.clean

So I am trying to get rid of gaps between a large number of polygons in QGIS using v.clean. I am able to successfully run the tool but the boundaries of very thin polygons end up changing quite dramatically which is something I do not want to have happen. I am guessing that I need to change the setting parameters but online resources for v.clean are not that common so I am not sure where to start. For context I am currently running the v.clean using only the snapping tool, and I have been experimenting with different snap tolerance and min area values.

This an example of what I do not want to happen:

Before v.clean:
[image]

After v.clean:
[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots showing your data? What do you want to happen when you have very thin polygonss?

Comment: Sharing sample data could also be helpful

Comment: This is an intrinsic problem with automated vertex correction. If you tell the software that all vertices are flexible to a certain degree, it will believe you. If you want a specific solution in certain cases you may need to implement your own solution.

Comment: It is impossible to delete gaps without changing any polygon boundaries. Do you want to find a solution for changing the boundaries of bigger polygons and keep the geometries of thin polygons untouched?

Comment: I will ask my client if I could share screen shots. It sounds like I might have to do some scripting given the responses on the page. Do you know if it is possible to only close the gaps outside of the polygon layer rather than inside as that would probably also work.

Comment: Do you know if the QGIS developers ever plan to improve v.clean or make a new tool similar to it?

Comment: @Ian Moffit v.clean is **not** a QGIS tool, but a GRASS tool than can be accessed in QGIS

Comment: Your example showed what you didn't want to happen in polygons that don't appear to have gaps.  Do you have examples of the gaps you want to get rid of and how you want them handled?  Do you want them filled with new polygons, or do you want them merged to abutting polygons?

Comment: V.clean successfully fill the gaps in successfully. In my case I would like them merged to abutting polygons.

Comment: Could you create a small artificial, dataset that exposes the problems so people could make some tests? Add a sketch about the desired result, at least for me it is not obvious at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately I am allowed to share this data set.

Comment: Dont use v.clean. Instead dissolve everything into one polygon, fill holes, difference this and your original polygons to get the holes as new polygons, merge these with your original polygons, select them, [eliminate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=eliminate#eliminate-selected-polygons)

Comment: @BERA Is there a video that shows how to do this by chance? I do need to preserve the original attribute info for context.

Comment: You do not need to share your customers data. Any dataset that shows the behavior will do, therefore I asked if you could create a dataset for testing. You can most probably digitize a few polygons with about similar shapes and hide the location, CRS, and attributes of the original data.